# ANT- Loading Multiple Java files from Several packages

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I have several files scattered across several packages. I need to load the file one by one and perform operations using ANT but whenever I try, only one file gets loaded. For ex. I have 2 classes - **com.abc.one.One** and **com.bcd.two.Two** . The following script print both file name but only the first file as loaded file in both loop iterations

```
<target name="build" description="My Task">
        <for param="file">
                <path>
                        <fileset dir="C:\workspace\AntTest1" includes="**\*.java" />
                </path>
                <sequential>
                <echo message="@{file}" />
                <loadfile property="loadedFile" srcfile="@{file}" />
                <echo message="${loadedFile}" />
                </sequential>
        </for>
</target>
```

I have tried searching the documentation but could not find the concise explanation on how to use loadfile task. I suspected that this might be because ant uses immutable string but could not get workaround. I tried to split the job by creating new target but that does not help me either. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I know this could be done using Gradle, if you get stuck with Ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant property can only be set once, and after it is set, it is immutable.

It has been some time since my Ant days, but perhaps the following solution can work: For each file, make an [antcall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) call, with the file name as parameter. then, in the new target, load the file and perform your task. Notice that antcall can impact severely the runtime performance.

Comment: I understand your comment but I see that the parameter file is getting different values. Why does the immutable property not hold for that?